# Долой [программирование]!

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, удаление-метки

Так как весь сайт целиком и полностью посвящён программированию, то тег [программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) избыточен. Его следует удалить.

Если есть возможность, он должен быть запрещён для использования, например, при его добавлении может выводиться подсказка, что следует добавить более точный тег.

Comment: Я против. Все-таки бывают настолько общие вопросы, что к ним невозможно применить более уточненный тег.

Comment: @metalurgus, можно пример?

Comment: Надо убрать тег программирование, зато добавить тег быдлокодинг)

Comment: @polsok, вас не смущает, что окончательное решение было принято более двух лет назад? То есть это как бы некромантия получается.

Comment: @Arhad, а вы против некромантии? Тогда что тут делаете?

Comment: Странно, что автор задает вопрос без тега [программирование]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Если возникают сомнения, подойдём формально. На Stack Exchange существуют [формальные критерии для уничтожения тега](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191).

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Тег не добавляет информации о посте. Так как он может быть добавлен к 90% вопросов на сайте, он практически бессмысленный.

По той же причине тег бесполезен для фильтрации контента на сайте.

Никто не может сказать, что он специалист по "программированию". Если подпишешься на тег, обязательно будешь видеть вопросы, в которых ты не разбираешься.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Программирование — широкое понятие, которое сложно формализовать и невозможно прийти к однозначному определению.

Является ли администрирование программированием? А если нужно для разработки? А установка среды программирования? А если при этом используется скрипт на PS? Является ли запись макросов в ворде программированием? А если скрипт исправляется? Является ли рисование диаграмм программированием? А если по диаграммам генерируется код?

Понятие невозможно формализовать.

---

И что касается "вопросов, к которым нельзя применить более точный тег". Такие вопросы практически гарантированно слишком широкие и открыты для обсуждения и споров, чтобы вписываться в формат QA. Такие вопросы *оффтопичны*.

Если у вас есть контр-примеры — приведите их. В свою очередь гарантирую, что или к вопросу можно добавить более осмысленные теги, или ему не место на SO.

---

И наконец, на английском SO такого тега нет. Это прекрасный пример для подражания, которому мы должны следовать.

Comment: Не надо ни за кем следовать, и ни кому подражать - это касаемо последних слов. Тэг лучше оставить, для тех же блок-схем подойдет. Кто неправильно использует, по вашему мнению, всегда можно внести правку.

Answer (score 16):

Поддерживаю.

99% вопросов с такой меткой оффтопичны чуть более чем полностью. Ну это кроме того, что метка действительно ничего полезного о вопросе не говорит. Это мета-метка, и она должна быть выпилена.

Если кто-то, вполне вероятно новичок, сомневается какие метки для вопроса выбрать, для этого есть Мета или чат (для участников с репутацией).

По сравнению с ХК аудитория будет расширяться в том числе русскоговорящими участниками с SO, где мета-метки решено не использовать. Склоняюсь к тому, что сообщество в состоянии общими усилиями навести порядок в метках. И "метки ради метки" пропадут вовсе.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы оставил тег для вопросов в духе programmers.stackexchange.com, не связанных напрямую с кодом, но относящимся к программированию.

Comment: Вопросы на Programmers тоже имеют осмысленные теги: дизайн, архитектура, лицензирование, управление-проектами и т.п. Необходимости в мета-теге "программирование" я не вижу. Кроме того, сначала надо определиться, [разрешены ли вообще подобные вопросы](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/34/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2).

Comment: тогда это называется либо алгоритмизацией либо что-то вроде духа программирования.

Answer (score -2):

Не поддерживаю. 
Кроме программирования имеется куча вопросов по администрированию, базам данным и прочим смежным тематикам.

Comment: Под этот тег в любом случае попадает 90% вопросов на сайте, даже если позволить писать про администрирование, которое, как я понимаю, всё-таки изначально оффтопик. Какая польза от тега, который не позволяет фильтровать? Давайте тогда добавим тег "компьютеры", чего уж останавливаться на полпути.

Comment: @Anton Shevtsov Простите, а базы данных к программированию не относятся? кстати, метки администрирование нет, никто не запутался пока.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov нет

Comment: Оригинальный stackoverflow не содержит вопросов по администрированию. Они отправляются на Server Fault.

Answer (score -10):

согласен, вместо тега "программирования" нужно вроде этого: "серверные языки программирования" ))).   Лучше оставить только back-end и front-end