# Запретить [программирование]!

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, удаление-метки, чёрный-список-меток

В продолжение "[Долой [программирование]!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/52/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)"

Предлагаю наконец добить эту метку и запретить, чтобы вопросы с ней перестали появляться. На данный момент требуется участие верховной власти.

1. Удалить метку в заблокированных вопросах. Список: [программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).
2. Внести метку в [Чёрный Список](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-blacklist) (см. тж. [blacklist-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blacklist-request)).

Если с первой задачей справятся простые смертные ромбы, то для второй требуются связи местной власти с админами. Так как аналогичная метка на большом СО запрещена, думаю, аргументация излишня.

Comment: Аргументация, конечно, излишняя, но мне всегда нравились ваши длинные посты, так что я за аргументацию.

Comment: @VladD Аргументация удаления в посте по первой ссылке.

Comment: Не узнал вас в гриме )