# Предлагаю сжечь [информатику]

Tags: предложение, удаление-метки

Есть метка [информатика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0), у которой 40 вопросов и даже 2 подписчика:

> [image: информатика]

Но я не вижу в ней особого смысла, так же как его не было видно в [сожжённой ранее](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/52/176217) метке [программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

Метка [информатика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) слишком общая. Неясно какой круг задач она должна описывать, чтобы её нельзя было навестить на подавляющее большинство вопросов сайта. Куда лучше давать более конкретные метки, например, [база-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85) или [системы-счисления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f), про отдельные языки программирования я даже не говорю.

Comment: предлагал я как-то кое-что сжечь  и потом много нытья было что не трошьте и старые вопросы не тревошьььте) а то боязно вдруг репа уйдет с ответов 11-го года)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский метки репе не помеха. Вот если б знаки, то может затронуть.

Comment: Да там всего 40 вопросов. Можно без обсуждения метку удалить из всех ;)

Comment: @Visman а потом Квертии разные будут задавать вопросы: что и зачем... так хоть по голосам будет видно, что метка не нужна.

Comment: Жечь надо не метку, а мусор который в нее постят. Если нормальный практический вопрос касается, скажем, единиц измерения информации, метка "информатика" на нем нормально смотрится. А школьный задачи в топку.

Comment: @VadimTagil к Вам тот же вопрос, что и к ответчику ниже: Какое бы описание Вы предложили для такой метки, будь она оставлена?

Comment: перевод [соответствующей метки с английского SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/computer-science/info) ,зачем что-то придумывать?

Comment: @VadimTagil тем не менее там не указано **когда** следует использовать эту метку.

Comment: Как-бы подразумевается, что на пересечении computer science (архитектура эвм, теория алгоритмов, измерение информации и т.п.) с тематикой so (программирование). Т.е. типичная пограничная метка. Понятно, что на текущий момент там 90% шлака, но вот такие вопросы я считаю можно в нее пихать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/285290/Эмулятор-вычислительной-машины

Answer (score 2):

В школе понятие "информатика" включает следующие дисциплины:

1. математическая логика;
2. программирование;
3. курсы пользователя;
4. биты, байты и прочие измерения информации;
5. мочилово в контр-страйк, если учитель заболел.

Эта штука всеобъемлющая и неопределяемая, а в вопросах по метке полная мешанина из всего вышеперечисленного и даже больше, поэтому метка должна быть удалена.

Comment: Что школа вкладывает в понятие "Информатика" - не важно для SO

Comment: @VadimTagil Но используют-то метку в основном школьники. Посмотрите вопросы.

Answer (score -1):

Вроде бы вполне нормальная метка для вопросов по информатике. Не понимаю, чем не угодила. Программирование и информатика - это не одно и то же. По программированию тут большинство вопросов, поэтому в таком смысле она не нужна (хотя я бы и её для узкого круга вопросов оставил), а вот от информатики избавляться я вообще причин не вижу.

Comment: Какое бы описание Вы предложили для такой метки, будь она оставлена?

Comment: Сначала тоже хотел ее удалить, но посмотрев вопросы, передумал. Многие из них вполне точно соответствуют этой метке. Так что плюс за несжигание.

Comment: @Kromster тогда почему бы её не навесить на тысячи уже имеющихся вопросов? Ведь всё это информатика.

Comment: @alexolut считайте что информатика тождественна computer-science, то есть в ней теоретические вопросы о науке. А не практические (которых на SO овер95%)

Comment: @Kromster заметьте, что у нас уже есть метка [tag:теория] с кратким описанием.